# How to save data in custom action for rollback in WIX?

Tags: wix, dtf

Is there any way I can store data for rollback in a custom action using DTF in Wix? 
In this instance I need to keep track of what has been done to properly perform a rollback, and I don't know how to pass this information on from the custom action run during the install to the action running at rollback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your costing action can determine what the install and rollback activities are and pass this to the deferred, rollback and commit custom actions respectively.   Otherwise you can also have your install custom action write a temp file and then have your rollback custom action read it.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is so obvious that it never entered my mind. A temp file logging the operation will work perfectly in my situation. I just thought maybe there was some other preferred way of saving state for rollback, but this will work just great. Thank you very much! :)